# Dual booting windows 10 and Fedora

Tags: fedora, windows, dual-boot

I have 2 hard drives , an old one on which i have Fedora installed and use it daily and a new one which a friend gave me and runs Windows 10 . I am going to do dual boot fedora and windows 10 , do you have any tips on how to dual boot so i don't mess up. Also what utilities can i use to minimize the time needed to reinstall all my programs and transfer files ?